# How to shrink string by using Realloc

Tags: c, string, realloc

First time asking a question here:
well I need to take the original string
and remove the spaces and numbers from the string
I need to use the exact amount of memory.

For some reason, the string is fine in the beginning
but then it prints garbage values:

original string: `"abcd2 34fty    78 jurt#"`
what needed to be done: `abcdftyjurt#`

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <string.h>

/* Function declarations */

/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Ex1();
char* clearDigitsAndSpaces(char*);
/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Ex2();

/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Ex3();

/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Declarations of other functions */

int main() {
    int select = 0, i, all_Ex_in_loop = 0;
    printf("Run menu once or cyclically?\n(Once - enter 0, cyclically - enter other number) ");
    if (scanf("%d", &all_Ex_in_loop) == 1)
        do {
            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                printf("Ex%d--->%d\n", i, i);
            printf("EXIT-->0\n");
            do {
                select = 0;
                printf("please select 0-3 : ");
                scanf("%d", &select);
            } while ((select < 0) || (select > 3));
            switch (select) {
            case 1: Ex1(); break;
            case 2: Ex2(); break;
            case 3: Ex3(); break;
            }
        } while (all_Ex_in_loop && select);
        return 0;
}

/* Function definitions */

void Ex1() {
    char input[] = "abcd2 34fty    78 jurt#";
    char *temp = NULL;
    temp = clearDigitsAndSpaces(input);
    printf("%s\n ", temp);
    free(temp);
}

char *clearDigitsAndSpaces(char *old_string) {
    char *new_string;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int size = strlen(old_string);
    new_string = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    assert(new_string); /*Memory allocation check*/
    while (old_string[i]) {
        if (old_string[i] != ' ' && (old_string[i] > '9' || old_string[i] < '0')) {
            new_string[j++] = old_string[i];
        } else {
            //size -= 1;
            new_string = (char *)realloc(new_string, size - 1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    assert(new_string);
    //printf("%s", new_string);
    return new_string;
}

void Ex2() {
}

void Ex3() {
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: No-code-look comment: did you NULL terminate your string? I think the OP meant to tag it as C.

Comment: Just use [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit) on your std::string.

Comment: As @gsamaras hints, you need: `int size = strlen(old_string) + 1;` to accommodate the `nul` terminator. (The `strlen` return value doesn't include it.)

Comment: Don't forget to count the NUL terminating char, thus `strlen(...)+1` and don't forget to copy it at the end...

Comment: OT: regarding: `int size = strlen(old_string);  The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, which is an 'long  unsigned' value.  This statement is trying to assign that `unsigned long` value into a (much shorter) signed value.  For small number, this will result in the desired value.  However, as the numbers get larger the sign of the result can/will become negative.

Comment: OT: regarding: `new_string = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));` 1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  Suggest removing that cast.  2)  As with most C library functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` to output to `stderr`, both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `new_string = (char *)realloc(new_string, size - 1);`  1) in C, do not cast the result.  2) the function: `realloc()` can fail.  Therefore, always assign the returned value to a 'temp' variable, check that the returned value is not NULL before assigning to the target variable.   Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the pointer to the allocated memory is 'lost', resulting in a unrecoverable memory leak

Comment: OT regarding: `int select = 0,`  `select()` is a well known C library function.  It is a poor programming practice to use function names as variable names.  That function is exposed by `#include <unistd.h>` and by `#include <select.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is you must allocate one extra byte for the null terminator.

You can avoid using `realloc()` by first scanning the source string to determine the allocation size and then use a separate loop to copy the contents:

```c
char *clearDigitsAndSpaces(const char *src) {
    char *new_string;
    size_t size = 1; // 1 extra byte for the null terminator.

    for (size_t i = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (src[i] != ' ' && !(src[i] >= '0' && src[i] <= '9'))
            size++;
    }
    new_string = malloc(size);
    if (new_string) {
        size_t j = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (src[i] != ' ' && !(src[i] >= '0' && src[i] <= '9'))
                new_string[j++] = src[i];
        }
        new_string[j] = '\0';  // set the null terminator
    }
    return new_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: you need to understand the difference between the *length* of a C-string and the *size* of a C-string.  The length does not include the null terminator.  The size does.  So this snippet:

```
int size = strlen(old_string);
new_string = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
```

needs to be

```
int size = strlen(old_string) + 1;
new_string = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
```

(note that if you're using Unicode in Windows, with `wchar_t` instead of `char`, then the size in bytes is twice the length, plus 2 - each character is two bytes, as well as the null terminator aka 'sentinel')

---

Secondly: I would suggest you use parenthesis to be explicit about intention.  It may not be "absolutely necessary", but there would be no doubt about the intention when someone else reads your code.  Also avoid indexing the same thing repeatedly.  Change:

```
if (old_string[i]!=' ' && (old_string[i] > '9' || old_string[i]< '0'))
```

to:

```
char oldChar = old_string[i];
if ((oldChar != ' ') 
    && ((oldChar > '9') || (oldChar < '0'))
   )
```

---

Finally, you need to emplace a null character at the end.  You don't need to realloc; just use not all of the buffer.  Change:

```
new_string = (char*)realloc(new_string, size-1);
```

to:

```
new_string[j++] = '\0';

// PS: if you really want to realloc, then add "new_string = (char*)realloc(new_string, j);" after writing the null character.
```

Also - if you change the `malloc` to a `calloc`, you won't need to write a null terminator, since the entire buffer would be nulled before you copied anything to it.

Furthermore, I would add a defensive limit check to `i` in the while loop to ensure it cannot go on ad-infinitum.